# losing my objects at cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, caching

I am using IIS7 and c# and mysql. and I put some objects into asp.net cache system with sql keywords. it has very simple logic.put the selected dataset into cache with the given sql keyword.

here is the problem. when I call my site with www.abc.com it works normal. while surfing in abc.com after second click firstly filled dataset becomes empty datasets and my site start showing empty lists.

I tried changing keys to some static words and copy datasets then cache them but no success so far.

I hope I explained well. http://beta.mpazari.com is the place if you like to see and at red boxes dropdowns is the lists should have been filled with data.

here is the my fill function

```
public void Fill(ref DataSet ds, string sql, DateTime? cacheTime, string key)
    {
        if (key == null) key = sql;
        if (cacheTime == null) cacheTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(generalCacheExpiarionTimeInMinutes);
        if (cache[key] != null) { ds = (DataSet)cache[key]; return; }
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["motorConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter myda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            if (ds == null) ds = new DataSet();

            ds.Clear();
            myda.Fill(ds);
            cache.Insert(key, ds.Copy(), null, cacheTime.Value, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,null);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have to post some code to get an answer to this.
How are you putting it in the cache? What dependancies/timing options are you using?

Comment: I need to explain that I tried to add dataset copy or ds itself but no success. that exmple is copying dataset and puts new object into cache.

Comment: I am still having this problem and I just realized that when I put dataset into memory it loses column names strange.

Comment: Have you tried caching your business objects instead?

Comment: I dont think there will be any problem then what I am trying to do is cache dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Cache are you using?  ASP.NET has several places that you can cache...I would suspect that you might be putting this in the cache that is disposed of at the end of each request.

**See these...**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx 
(Context Cache...persists for the life of the app domain)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx 
(Request Cache...persists until the end of the Request)